# Root logger ignoring logger level

Tags: python, logging

Root logger doesn't log when (I think) it should:

```
import logging

# NOTE: I make sure to set the root logger level to logging.DEBUG
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This is a debugging test.')
```

From my understanding this should log something but it does nothing.
Quick Google searches didn't help me to figure this issue out, neither did the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

In the other hand, if I use `logging.warning` instead of `logging.debug`, it does work.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Checking the current level with `logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()` indicates me that the level is still at `30`, like before the call of `logging.basicConfig`.

Checking `logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` effectively tells me that the root logger level isn't enabled for `logging.DEBUG`.

Comment: Your code snippet works. Could it be that you called `logging.debug('some text')` already somehwere else before in your real code? This automatically configures the root logger and your `basicConfig` will be ignored.

Comment: @SmCaterpillar Brillant sir! I did read something about that but I didn't understand it quite well, so that was it! Feel free to post it as an answer as well!

Comment: You're welcome, since your answer already mentions the solutions, there's really no need for another one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Turned out OP's (me) trouble was due to already calling `logging.debug` before `logging.basicConfig`, thus settings the config to defaults and the call to `logging.basicConfig` was ignored as pointed out by @SmCaterpillar.

*Although*, this alternative solution allows you to "force" root logger level after a `basicConfig` has already been set, could still be useful!

---

Found a "solution":

```
# […] Previous code

# Sets the root logger level
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('Test')  # Displays 'DEBUG:root:Test'
```

But it doesn't carry out the format I gave in in `logging.basicConfig`.

That said I'm already satisfied: It is already some kind of progress. Logging even with not exactly the format I expected is always better than no logging at all.

Comment: This is so confusing.